# C# Generics constraint with Interface to a method

Tags: c#, generics, interface, constraints

probably the title is not right but i can't figure out something more precise.

I have this class:

```
    Transport<T> where T: ISomething
```

I have another class where i can have my "Transport" class with his generics that implement my ISomething. Like This:

```
    public class Route 
    {
        Transport<ISomething> Transport;
        public Route(Transport<ISomething> t)
        {
            Transport = t;
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to call my constructor

```cs
    Transport<Potatoes> myTransport = GetAllPotatoes();
    
    Route myRoute = new Route(myTransport);
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm new to generics and (as non native english speaker) i can't use the right keywords to find the answer myself.

Thanks.

EDIT for clarity:
Potatoes implements ISomething.

Comment: Can you show what members you have in the `Transport` class?

Comment: a `Transport<Potatoes>` is *not* a `Transport<ISomething>`. Generic parameterisation doesn't cause the constructed type to gain the same inheritance/implementation relationships of the original types.

Comment: what does it consist of your Potatoes class? it also implemented from ISomething interface?

Comment: I actually don't think you need Generics here _at all_. You `Transport` `ISomething` anyway on your `Route`.

Comment: of course my Potatoes class implement ISomething

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it with a covariant interface... in your case:

```
public interface ISomething {
}

public interface ITransport<out T> where T : ISomething
{
}

public class Transport<T> : ITransport<T> where T: ISomething
{
}

public class Potatoes : ISomething {
}

public class Route 
{
  ITransport<ISomething> Transport;
  public Route(ITransport<ISomething> t)
  {
    Transport = t;
   }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Transport<Potatoes> myTransport = null /* or getAllPotatoes */;   
        Route myRoute = new Route(myTransport);
    }
}
```

Note that `Route` now takes an `ITransport<T>`, not a `Transport<T>`.

Covariance in classes doesn't work, you need an interface for that.

This doesn't do anything, but just so you see it compiles: https://dotnetfiddle.net/T2Yd8N

Answer (score 1):

You can make the route generic as well, like so:

```cs
public class Route<T>
    {
        Transport<T> Transport;
        public Route(Transport<T> t)
        {
            Transport = t;
        }
    }
```

Then you can create a route as

```cs
   Transport<Potatoes> myTransport = GetAllPotatoes();
    
    Route<Potatoes> myRoute = new Route<Potatoes>(myTransport);
```

I guess however, that's not what you want, because you want to be able to create routes that are not generic. In this case, you need to have a non-generic base class of either `Route` or `Transport`.

For instance:

```cs
public interface ITransport {}

public class Transport<T> : ITransport 
where T: ISomething
{
}

public class Route
    {
        ITransport Transport;
        public Route(ITransport t)
        {
            Transport = t;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What i would need is to feed my Route constructor with a Transport<anyobject that implement ISomething>.And maybe mine is totally not the right approach.  I would like to have my Route as flexible as possible due to my "transport" variety

Comment: The question is whether the Route needs to have access to the properties/methods of ISomething or of Transport. If the route doesn't need to know the actual ISomething, the above suggestion should work for you.

Comment: yhea it should use ISomething methods and properties

Comment: Your Transport knows about ISomething, your Route likely shouldn't. If the Route needs to have access to fields of ISomething, add corresponding wrapper methods to Transport.  You can also make Transport _implement_ ISomething.